# C#: Have my program call methods on a running process on the same machine

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, ipc

I'm writing a C# tool which will do dependency checks for other programs. One way I do that is I iterate through the process array and see if a certain process name is found. If so, I would like to call a certain method on the process (which I know it supports). That method returns a dictionary. I would like to take that dictionary output and use it in my dependency checker.

All this happens on the same workstation not across a network.

How can I do this? I can my program communicate and call a method on a process, store that result? Do I have to use IPC? .NET remoting? How??

I've never used any of those tools. I would like to know where to start>

Can someone give me some advice please?

I'm using .NET 2.0 so I donot have WCF. Any other ideas?

Comment: You cannot call methods directly on objects that live inside a process, and the process itself does not expose any methods for such interaction. As such you will need to use some sort of IPC. If you wrote the program in question you can send signals to it using synchronization objects (like semaphores or mutexes), but that's only useful when you do not need to inject data from outside the process.

Comment: It would probably be much easier to upgrade to .Net 4 than to try to do what you want pre-WCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some form of .NET Remoting implementation would probably be the method of choise for you. This does of course require that you are creating the code for both of the two processes.

If you are not in control of the other process and that process doesn't have a documented interface for interprocess communication, then I don't think you can access methods within that process.

Answer (score 2):

You could use named pipes in WCF for this:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

This tutorial shows a simple example of what I believe you are trying to do.

Comment: Link can not be opened